# function parameter string pass by reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

```
void print(const string& str){
    cout << str <<endl;;
}

int main(){
    print(string("asdf"));
}
```

I think I can understand this way
there is a temporary string object created and it is passed to the function by reference. The parameter str is actually exactly the same object as that temporary string object.

But how about if I replace the call with print("asdf");?
What is exactly happening in this case?
I know implicit conversion is involved. But I am not sure when and how it is done?
I mean is it there is a temporary string object created as well?

Comment: The same thing will be done implicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

> What is exactly happening in this case? I know implicit conversion is involved.

Exactly the same thing happens, but implicit conversion is involved, instead of explicit call to the constructor.

---

> But I am not sure when and how it is done?

Quote from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> Implicit conversions are performed whenever an expression of some type T1 is used in context that does not accept that type, but accepts some other type T2

---

> I mean is it there is a temporary string object created as well?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since `string` has constructor which takes `const char*` (`string (const char* s)`), and this constructor is not marked `explicit`, compiler will build code equivalent to that in your question.